# the computer can't import pip and install things with it

Tags: pip

I tried to download python libraries using pip install like pygame, pytube... but it just won't work and give me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\program files\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.models import Request, Response
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import urllib3
ImportError: cannot import name 'urllib3' from 'pip._vendor' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip\_vendor\__init__.py)
```

I wrote the import statement in python: from pip._vendor import urllib3 and I got the same error, it the pc can't import it

how can I fix that, if I can't, can I just download libraries from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
python -m pip install pytube
```